# Java Streams: Create Map Using Multiple List of different object types

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to create a Map of objects using multiple lists of different object types. I want to take an example so that it'd be more clear and easy to discuss.

```
class Employee {
Long id;
String name;
// getters, setters, and toString
}

class Department {
Long id;
String name;
// getters, setters, and toString
} 

class EmployeeDepartment {
Long id;
Long employeeId;
Long deptId;
// getters, setters, and toString
}

class Subject {
Long id;
String name;
// getters, setters, and toString
}

class EmployeeSubject {
Long id;
Long employeeId;
Long subjectId;
// getters, setters, and toString
}
```

Now, I have

```
List<Employee> emplList;
List<EmployeeDepartment> emplDeptList;
List<EmployeeSubject> emplSubList;
```

I want to get a Map by which I can make a search of employee using : deptId, and subjectId

Something like

```
Map<List<Long, Long>, List<Employee>> deptSubToEmpMap;
// representing Map<List<deptId, subId>, List<empl>>

// Or
Map<Long, Map<Long, List<Employee>> deptToSubToEmpMap;
// representing Map<deptId, Map<subId, List<empl>>
```

or
any other convenient form if it's better than above representation.

> Note: I'm a newbie to Java Streams

Comment: It is better to use your 2nd approach

Comment: But did you give it a try at least? It could have been `Map<LookupRequest, List<Employee>>` as well. Few of your classes are unrelated as they stand for now.

Comment: Hi Naman, all are of different class objects, not sure from where to start :|

Comment: All I could do was build `Map<List<Long, Long>, List<EmployeeDepartment>>` and `Map<List<Long, Long>, List<EmployeeSubject>>` seperately

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `EmployeeSubjectDepartment` that will hold relation between employee, department and subject, as below,

```
@Getter@Setter
class EmployeeSubjectDepartment{
    Long empId;
    Long deptId;
    Long subId;

    public EmployeeSubjectDepartment(Long empId, Long deptId, Long subId) {
        this.empId = empId;
        this.deptId = deptId;
        this.subId = subId;
    }
}
```

And then merge `emplDeptList` and `emplSubList` to get `emplyees`

```
List<EmployeeSubjectDepartment> employeeSubjectDepartments = emplDeptList.stream()
                .flatMap(dept -> emplSubList.stream()
                        .filter(sub -> dept.employeeId.equals(sub.employeeId))
                        .map(sub -> new EmployeeSubjectDepartment(dept.employeeId, dept.deptId, sub.subjectId)))
                .collect(toList());

Map<Long, Map<Long, List<Long>>> result = employeeSubjectDepartments.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(EmployeeSubjectDepartment::getDeptId,
                groupingBy(EmployeeSubjectDepartment::getSubId, mapping(e -> e.empId, toList()))));
```

This will result in `Map` with `List` of employeeIds.

If you want the `List` of employees, create `EmployeeSubjectDepartment` as below,

```
 class EmployeeSubjectDepartment{
        Employee emp;
        Long deptId;
        Long subId;
    }
```

And then merge `emplDeptList` and `emplSubList` to get  and map to `emplyees` from `emplList`

```
List<EmployeeSubjectDepartment> employeeSubjectDepartments = emplDeptList.stream()
                .flatMap(dept -> emplSubList.stream()
                        .filter(sub -> dept.employeeId.equals(sub.employeeId))
                        .map(sub -> new EmployeeSubjectDepartment(emplList.stream().filter(e -> e.id == sub.employeeId).findAny().orElse(null), dept.deptId, sub.subjectId)))
                .collect(toList());

Map<Long, Map<Long, List<Employee>>> result = employeeSubjectDepartments.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(EmployeeSubjectDepartment::getDeptId,
                groupingBy(EmployeeSubjectDepartment::getSubId, mapping(e -> e.emp, toList()))));
```

This may not be a perfect solution but you can get the desired result.